# Is this an example of dependency injection?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, coding-style

Consider the following example:

```
class ExampleController
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        $newTestMethod = (new AnotherController)->testTwo();
    }
}
```

As we can see in the example above, I got new instance from a controller inside another controller.
**Is this code an example of dependency injection?**
If the answer is yes, then what way do you suggest to write the above code optimally?

Comment: No. Nothing is being _injected_ here. This is, in fact, a hard dependency because you are tying the two controllers together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. The Dependency Injection is nothing but injecting a dependency explicitly. Have [a look here](https://codeinphp.github.io/post/dependency-injection-in-php/).

Your code could look like this:

```
class ExampleController
{
    public function testOne(AnotherController $anotherController)
    {
        $newTestMethod = $anotherController->testTwo();
    }
}
```

Here you have to really inject the dependency to use `testOne()`, the argument is explicit and reusable.